# Create and fill Labels (dynamic in Java)

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I used Windowbuilder/SwingDesigner/Jframe. 
I have following class:

```
        public class Tag {

            String name ="";

            long startTime;
            long endTime;
            long result;

            public String getName() {
                return name;
            }
            public void setName(String name) {
                this.name = name;
            }
            public long getStartTime() {
                return startTime;
            }
            public void setStartTime(long startTime) {
                this.startTime = startTime;
            }
            public long getEndTime() {
                return endTime;
            }
            public void setEndTime(long endTime) {
                this.endTime = endTime;
            }
            public long getResult() {
                return result;
            }
            public void setResult(long result) {
                this.result = result;
            }
        }
```

And following "class" where I use Tag and change the information:

```
        public class Runtracker extends JFrame 
        {
            private static Tag[] tags;
            void connect ( String portName ) throws Exception
            {
                CommPortIdentifier portIdentifier = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier(portName);
                if ( portIdentifier.isCurrentlyOwned() )
                {
                    System.out.println("Error: Port is currently in use");
                }
                else
                {
                    CommPort commPort = portIdentifier.open(this.getClass().getName(),2000);

                    if ( commPort instanceof SerialPort )
                    {
                        SerialPort serialPort = (SerialPort) commPort;
                        serialPort.setSerialPortParams(57600,SerialPort.DATABITS_8,SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);

                        while(true){
                            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                            InputStream in = serialPort.getInputStream();
                            if(in.read(buffer) > 0);
                            {
                                for(int i=0; i < tags.length; i++)
                                {
                                    String compare;
                                    compare = in.toString();
                                    if(tags[i].getName().equals(compare)){
                                        tags[i].setEndTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
                                        tags[i].setResult(tags[i].getEndTime() - tags[i].getStartTime());
//Here is the second update of my label, cause now i get the endtime and result                                         
                                    }

                                }
                                (new Thread(new SerialReader(in))).start();
                            }

                        }
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("Error: Only serial ports are handled by this example.");
                    }
                }     
            }

            public static class SerialReader implements Runnable 
            {
                InputStream in;

                public SerialReader ( InputStream in )
                {
                    this.in = in;
                }

                public void run ()
                {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    int len = -1;
                    try
                    {
                        while ( ( len = this.in.read(buffer)) > -1 )
                        {
                            String x = (new String(buffer,0,len));
                            try
                            {
                                Thread.sleep(1000);
                            } catch( Exception e)
                            {
                                System.out.println("Sleep error");
                            }

                            tags[tags.length+1].setName(x);
                            tags[tags.length+1].setStartTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
//here i have to create the label and fill the name and starttime in it
                        }
                    }
                    catch ( IOException e )
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }            
                }
            }

            private JPanel contentPane;

            /**
             * Launch the application.
             */
            public static void main(String[] args) {
                EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            Runtracker frame = new Runtracker();
                            frame.setVisible(true);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
```

I marked the places with commentar signs, where labels should be created or changed.

The output should be like:
Name starttime endtime result(endtime-starttime)
My idea was:

```
LabelName.setText(tags[tags.length+1].getName + tags[tags.length+1].getStartTime());
```

But it won´t update on the upper state, where we have to add endtime and result.

Comment: How are you expecting to access `tags[tags.length+1]` ? That's 2 above the max index!

Comment: The first thing you need to look at is [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/), Swing is not thread safe and you should never update the UI components from outside of the context of the EDT

Comment: so it is impossible?

Comment: 1) Tip: Add @MadProgrammer (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment. 2) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).